# python beautifulsoup to download specific .zip files from a website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am new to web scraping. I am trying to download only the weekly .zip files from the below website. I could able to parse the  label and couldn't go beyond that to download the weekly zip files.

https://download.cms.gov/nppes/NPI_Files.html

[html code for 'li' tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pl04m.png)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = "https://download.cms.gov/nppes/NPI_Files.html"
r = requests.get(URL)
#print(r.content)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
#print(soup.prettify())
links=[]

ref = soup.select('li')
#print(ref)

for i in ref:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://download.cms.gov/nppes/NPI_Files.html"
r = requests.get(URL)
#print(r.content)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
#print(soup.prettify())
links=[]

for ref in soup.select('div.bulletlistleft > ul > li')[2:]:
    zip ='https://download.cms.gov/nppes'+ref.a.get('href').replace('./','/')
    links.append(zip)
print(links)
```

**Output:**

```
['https://download.cms.gov/nppes/NPPES_Data_Dissemination_090522_091122_Weekly.zip', 'https://download.cms.gov/nppes/NPPES_Data_Dissemination_091222_091822_Weekly.zip', 'https://download.cms.gov/nppes/NPPES_Data_Dissemination_091922_092522_Weekly.zip']
```

Comment: thank you so much, it worked like a charm :) i have just changed to this

#links=[]

for ref in soup.select('div.bulletlistleft > ul > li')[2:]:
    zip ='https://download.cms.gov/nppes'+ref.a.get('href').replace('./','/')
    #links.append(zip)
    wget.download(zip)

Answer (score 0):

Access `a` tags if there are any:

```py
for i in ref:
    if i.a is not None:
        print(i.a.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either just select all links then filter them down to the weekly updates:

```
ref = [
    a for a in soup.select('a') if a.text
    and 'Weekly Update' in a.text
]
```

OR you can narrow down to a parent element before selecting the links:

```
ref = soup.find(
    'b', string='Weekly Incremental NPI Files'
).find_next('tr').select('a')
```

**Either way,** you'll end up with the same set of links:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following code will find the links, download the files, and unzip them.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
import zipfile

target_folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
base_url = "https://download.cms.gov/nppes"

url = f"{base_url}/NPI_Files.html"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

elms = soup.select('div.bulletlistleft > ul > li > a')
for elm in elms:
    zip_filename = elm.attrs['href'].lstrip('./')
    zip_full_url = "/".join((base_url, zip_filename))
    target_zip_path = os.path.join(target_folder, zip_filename)
    target_zip_dir = ".".join(target_zip_path.split('.')[:-1])
    urlretrieve(zip_full_url, target_zip_path)

    with zipfile.ZipFile(target_zip_path, 'r') as zip_file:
        zip_file.extractall(target_zip_dir)
```